# How to find which object was clicked in easeljs?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, createjs, easeljs

Please go through this code.

```
arrow_left.addEventListener("click",ans_eval);      
arrow_right.addEventListener("click",ans_eval);  //ans_eval is a function.
```

now if I want to know which object was clicked, how do I find out?

```
if(e.target.name==arrow_left){         is this the correct way??
}
```

How to do it?
When I defined arrow_left, I didn't specify any name for that object, so will `e.target.name` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the name, it should work fine just like this:

`if ( e.target == arrow_left ) { ...`

This of course requires that your method `ans_eval` can access to the `arrow_left`-variable, meaning that it will be called in the same context and the `addEventListener`.
Wether or not this is the case will only you know or you post the whole code in a js-fiddle.

Comment: There is more information here. Poster - please refrain from cross-posting stuff like this. http://community.createjs.com/discussions/tweenjs/493-how-to-call-a-function-after-tweening-is-completely-done

Answer (score 0):

Try giving names to the arrows before adding listeners, like:

```
arrow_left.name = 'arrow_left';
arrow_right.name = 'arrow_right';
```

and your function that listens for the mouse click should be like:

```
if ( e.target == 'arrow_left' ) { ...
```